# Work Equation for Constant Non-consercative Forces

Tags: energy-conservation, work

If work done by a **constant** conservative force where work is independent of path taken is:

$W=\vec{F}\cdot \Delta\vec{x}$  where $\vec{x}$ is displacement

Then work done by a **constant** non-conservative force where work is dependent of path taken is:

$W=\vec{F}\cdot \Delta d$  where $d$ is distance

?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @BillN i think the question is "what formula do i use to get the work for non-conservative forces?"

Comment: @KyleKanos I appreciate your effort, but we shouldn't have to infer what the question is, especially when there is no question asked at all. A "?" is not a question. Why didn't the OP respond, rather than you?

Comment: @BillN I don't know why OP didn't/hasn't responded, but I did because this question was in the review queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of conservative force, the path does not matter. In the case of non-conservative force, it does. By definition:
$$W=\int_C \vec{F} \cdot \mathrm{d} \vec{s}$$
Where $C$ is the path, let's say, from $A$ to $B$. In the case of conservative force, there exists a potential for the force, and the work done is simply $W=U(B)-U(A)$. But in the case of non-conservative force, there is no potential, and you should parametrize the integral.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say for a constant force. Can we get rid of the integral then?

$W=\vec{F}\cdot \Delta d$

Comment: If a force is constant, then it does not depend on the location, so the work can't depend on the path, so it's conservative. And yes if the force is constant, then $W=\vec{F}\cdot\Delta \vec{x}$. Alternatively, if the work is constant, then it's curl is $\vec{0}$, so it's conservative.

Comment: Non-conservative forces can't be constant? What about a constant kinetic friction of $F_k=30N$?

Comment: @NoName I think the friction is path dependent.

Comment: @NoName the magnitude of the friction vector might be constant, but it's direction is opposite to the direction of the velocity. Slightly different approach is that friction converts work to heat and not to energy.

Comment: @NoName Just for clarification, a force that is constant only in magnitude is not conservative. The direction also has to be constant with respect to the path. If the former were true then frction, etc. would be conservative.

Answer (score 1):

Work is *defined* as

$$ W = \int_{r_i}^{r_f} \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{r} $$

regardless of whether $\mathbf{F}$ is conservative or nonconservative.

---

However, you ask about the case of a constant conservative force. A conservative force is one such that

- It can be written as the gradient of a potential $\mathbf{F} = -\vec\nabla U$ and
- The net work done by the force between two points in space is independent of the path, i.e. if

$$ \vec\nabla \times \mathbf{F} = \vec 0 $$

or (equivalently)

$$\oint_{C} \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{r} = 0,$$

where $C$ is a closed path. Both of these conditions indicate that a conservative force must have a position dependency. Thus it is not possible to have a conservative force that is constant-magnitude with respect to position.

That said you can have a constant-magnitude nonconservative force. Friction, tension, and other kinds of constraint or dissipative forces are just some examples -- they don't have corresponding potentials, and they don't depend on the position of the object.

Comment: I think the friction depends on the position, because it's $\vec {F}=-\frac{F}{\dot{x}} \vec{\dot{x}}$. If it were constant, then the curl would be $0$, so there would be a potential, because all vector field with a $0$ curl has a potential.

Comment: @Botond It's not clear where that formula is coming from. Friction is generally constant as $\mu F_N$, and air resistance is either $-a\dot x$ or $-b\dot x^2$. It's not enough for it to depend on position, it has to satisfy $\nabla \times \mathbf{F} = 0$.

Comment: I wanted to say with it that the friction has a constant magnitude (The $F$ stands for it's magnitude), but it's direction is opposite to the direction of the velocity. So that's why i multiplied it with an unit vector pointing at the opposite direction of the velocity: $-\frac{\vec{v}}{v}$.

Comment: That's the reason why I think that your statement "That said you can have a constant nonconservative force." is false.

Comment: @Botond Oh, you are correct. I was being loose with my language -- my apologies. I was trying to mean forces that are constant in magnitude only.